# Pure Javascript getting an elementByClass adding hidden

Tags: javascript

I have the following Javascript code:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  var el = document.getElementsByClassName('video');
  el.className += " hidden";
  // el[0].style.visibility = 'hidden'; 
}, 3000);
```

I wanted the script to add an class **hidden** to the video class. Wat is wrong about my code?

Your sincerely

Comment: As the method name suggests, the return value of [`.getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) is a collection of elements. What you already know, based on the commented part in the code...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the iteration part. The method `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` of elements. So, you need to iterate over the `NodeList`

```
setTimeout(
function(){

var el = document.getElementsByClassName('video');

for(var element of el){
el.className += "hidden";
}

}
,3000);
```

Comment: [`for...in...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...in_statement) is meant for objects and not arrays (or array-like objects) -> [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Thanks for the post. Try it out but it doesn't works well. I'm just an beginner @ Javascript. Because of de getElementsByClassName it makes automatic ly an array, because is checks all the classes right?                                   Why does el.className[0]+= " hidden"; nog work?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, you are right, was writing some c# code, corrected the post to use `for of` loop.

Comment: @LeviNijveldt, you need to write it like `el[0].className = "hidden"` instead of  `el.className[0] = " hidden"`

Comment: That was the answer i've been looking for. Thank Agalo.

Comment: @LeviNijveldt Glad it helped.